# JSON response parameters

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using this:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

var responseText=httpGet('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

to get JSON response as fallow:

```
{
    "response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
      "40": {
        "AccountNote": {
          "id": "40",
          "type": "azx",
          "account_id": "1111",
          "created": "2015-02-11 11:12:03",
          "note": "test"
        }
      },
      "42": {
        "AccountNote": {
          "id": "42",
          "type": "azx",
          "account_id": "1111",
          "created": "2015-02-11 11:27:56",
          "note": "zzzzzzz"
        }
      }
    },
    "errors": [],
    "errorMessage": null
  }
}
```

I want to get values of all note parameters.
I know i can do that using this:

```
var obj=JSON.parse(responseText);
console.log(obj.response.data[40].AccountNote.note+' '+obj.response.data[42].AccountNote.note);
```

I don't know how many data in response.data will be. I don't know their names either (in these example '40' and '42).
So i tried something like this:

```
var text='';
for(var i=0;i<obj.response.data.length;i++)
    text+=obj.response.data[i].AccountNote.note;
```

but this of course doesn't work.
How i can do the trick?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can iterate through them using `for` loop like so:

```
var text='';
for(var i in obj.response.data)
{
    text += obj.response.data[i].AccountNote.note;
}
```

Variable i is index of element in the array obj.response.data so you don't have to worry about random indexes anymore.

Comment: Problems like _"How to iterate over objects"_ have been answered on SO plenty of times already. I'd recommend close-voting as duplicate, instead of answering such questions, since the OP should've searched a bit before asking on SO.

Comment: @traffic check this: http://jsfiddle.net/54peq372/